# Waffle SSPI Kerberos Single Sign On: Configuring the Encryption Ciphers, and Debugging

Tags: java, kerberos, sspi, waffle

> *How can we configure which Encryption Ciphers a Java Waffle SSPI*
>   *Kerberos Single Sign On (SSO) client should use?*
>
> *How can we best debug which ciphers*
>   *are actually being used by the client and server?*

**Background**

We need to restrict the Encryption Ciphers used for Kerberos SSO, removing ciphers now considered weak.

**Our Setup**

The Java Application Server implements SSO via pure Java GSSAPI.

The Java Client implements SSO by two configurable SSO APIs:

- On Linux or Windows 10 without Credential Guard active: via pure Java GSSAPI.
- On Windows 10 with Credential Guard Active: via Java Waffle + Microsoft SSPI API
  .

The Kerberos “back-end” is Windows Active Directory.

**What we already know**

On the pure Java GSSAPI implementations (Server and Client) we can set the system property `java.security.krb5.conf` to configure a Krb5.conf file in which we can explicitly configure the encryptions types e.g.

```
[libdefaults]

default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts

default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts

permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part4.html

With GSSAPI we can get debug information with the the system property `sun.security.krb5.debug=true`

However on the Waffle SSPI client, neither system properties have any effect. In retrospect this is not surprising because SSPI is not calling the java Runtime kerberos code.

My guess is that SSPI takes the permitted encryption types from the Windows Operating System, and that we may not be able to configure the types from the java application.

The Waffle website suggests the following link for Kerberos Debugging:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/262177/how-to-enable-kerberos-event-logging

Comment: Why not just disable the use of those weaker ciphers in AD for the users and service principals in question? The client is going to solicit which ciphers it can use. If AD only returns the ones you deem secure, the client can only ever use those.

Comment: @Steve that would back up my hunch that "...SSPI takes the encryption types from the Windows OS...", so if the users and service are properly setup in AD, nothing else needs doing. This contrasts with pure Java GSSAPI which by its nature is not so tightly integrated with Windows / AD, and requires me to configure the encryption types via the krb5.conf file