# Waffle SSPI how to set the SPNEGO mutualFlag

Tags: java, sspi, waffle

While trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60422387/the-token-supplied-to-the-function-is-invalid-error-when-validating-spnego-res) we noticed a difference between the SPNEGO Requests (KRB_AP_REQ) from our GSSAPI and SSPI client implementations:

- Using GSSPI the mutalFlag is set to False
- Using SSPI the mutualFlag is set to True.

In our Java code calling GSSAPI we can explicitly set the flag to true or false as required, but I have found no way to do this using Waffle / SSPI.

Searching [the Waffle code on Github](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/0c6f832222b59537847281adf7d2959583809dff/Source/WindowsAuthProvider/Secur32.cs) for “mutual” gave only one hit: for the constant `ISC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH`

**Is there a way to set the mutualFlag explicitly via Waffle / SSPI?**

i.e. something equivalent to the GSSAPI code below:

```
GSSContext context = gssManager.createContext(serverName, mechOid, null, GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
context.requestMutualAuth(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not recommend to disable mutual auth. Waffle abstraction is too high. We have the same issue: wanted to modify context flags. We had to modify source code and recompile. Raise an issue with Waffle and provide a PR at best.

Code on question is here: https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/0c6f832222b59537847281adf7d2959583809dff/Source/JNA/waffle-jna/src/main/java/waffle/windows/auth/impl/WindowsSecurityContextImpl.java#L117-L119

Comment: that confirms my suspicion that setting these flags will require changes to Waffle code. Before I submit a CR on the Waffle Github I will upgrade from Waffle 1.9.1 to Waffle 2.2.1 and JNA from 4.5.1 to 5.5.0, because that is the first thing they will ask me to do. Will be next week before I have a chance of testing this on client site.